# How to throw exception from lambda to calling method?

Tags: java

I have this simplified example of my method :

```
private void bulkIndex(String filePath, RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception  {
    RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> request
            .getHeaders()

    ResponseExtractor<Void> responseExtractor = response -> {

        try {
            indexData(filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e; //I want to throw this to the caller of the BulkIndex method
        }
        return null;
    };
    restTemplate.execute(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, responseExtractor) ;
}
```

In its current state, the code will simply highlight an error at the "Throw e" line with a message : `Unhandled exception type Exception`

I'm trying to chain the exceptions all the way up the call stack but I don't know how to get around this lambda method.

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException("message")` or some custom Exception `public class YourException extends RuntimeException{}`

Answer (score 1):

`responseExtractor` is an object of an anonymous class (created through lambda expression), the latter being a child of the `ResponseExtractor` interface.

Your class is supposed to override [extractData](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResponseExtractor.html#extractData-org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse-) method of the `ResponseExtractor` interface. You cannot throw an `Exception` from this method, since the `extractData` of `ResponseExtractor` throws only `IOException`.

*Hence you can throw only `IOException` or its child classes from your lambda expression.*

You can refer to [this codejava.net article](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/12-rules-of-overriding-in-java-you-should-know) for a complete overview of overriding.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the exception in a RuntimeException so it is "unchecked", but then you have to be careful about how it propagates and where you will catch it:

```
interface Thingy<T> {
    public T doThings();
}

abstract class ExceptionWrappingThingy<T> implements Thingy<T> {
    public final T doThings() {
        try {
            return doThrowyThings();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public abstract T doThrowyThings();
}
```